# PropertyPlaceholders in web.xml

Tags: spring, configuration, java-ee-6, placeholder

I'm using the following:

- Spring 3.1
- Java EE 6 (GlassFish 3.1.2)
- Maven for project builds, etc
- Ant for live deployment

We have a bunch of environments at work: DEV, UAT, TRAINING, PROD, etc. In our TRAINING environment a request has been made for me to up the session timeout to 8 hours. It is 2 hours in all other environments. What I'd love to do is simply use a property placeholder in `web.xml`. But I don't think this is possible:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>${session.timeout}</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The solutions I have thought of are:

1. Use Maven filtering - I **really** do not wish to do this. It would mean a separate war for training.
2. Remove the session timeout from `web.xml` and configure GlassFish in TRAINING to timeout after 8 hours - I don't like this too much, as I'd prefer to keep all our environments pure and in sync.
3. Set this manually in some initialisation code. Yuck.

I should mention that we use `<env>.properties` files to configure the web-app. The properties file is selected using a VM argument.

Can anyone think of another, nicer solution?

Thanks in advance,
Muel.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set it in some initialisation code then you'd be able to fetch it from spring. The web.xml is the first thing that is read so no pre-processing is possible on it.

So why not do that create some "manual initialisation code" which is deployed with the war that loads the session timeout from spring.

Comment: Aye, this is what I had in mind in number 3. Was hoping to avoid this, but I prefer it to the other two options. That said, if I spend some time to create some auto deploy scripts for GlassFish itself (the app server not the web app), then this is my preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960764/how-to-set-session-timeout-dynamically-in-java-web-applications) on SO, There can be two ways but not sure -

1. You can have different web.xml files for each environment and build the war file with corresponding web.xml. This is perfectly possible.
2. You can use custom `HttpSessionListener` as shown in the above link. Though it has session time out set from hard coded value, I would try accessing context initialization parameter from the servlet like

   ```
   Session().getServletContext().getInitParameter("paramName");
   ```

and will define init params with different session timeout values for different environment. I have not tested this code so not sure if you get context params.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your number 1 is equivalent to using Maven filtering. It's (generally speaking) bad practice to have a different WAR per environment. Regarding your number 2, this combined with Spring is what I had in mind for my number 3!