# How to prevent managedBean session times out?

Tags: jsf, session-timeout, managed-bean

I'm working on JEE 6 projet where the client need sometimes to prevent the session from times out. I want to use a **Boolean Check Box** to allow the ever user to **Stay connected** or not like he wants.

I am tempted by the following technique, where **myType** must be : **client** or **server** ;

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>#{mySession.myType}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hi this topic was already discussed here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960764/how-to-set-session-timeout-dynamically-in-java-web-applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960764/how-to-set-session-timeout-dynamically-in-java-web-applications) And here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382895/session-timeout-in-web-xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382895/session-timeout-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem in other way :

1. I've not use **javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD**
2. In my **web.xml** i've used : **session-timeout = 20**
3. In my **loginForm**
4. i've changed the *action form* from **j_security_check** To **j_security_check.jsp** by creating a **jsp file**.
5. i've added in the *login form* a **checkbox** to know if the user want to stay connected or not.
6. In my managedBean i check the **KEEP_CONNECT** value, *to disable timeOut until the manual deconnexion* : **userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);** *Or to keep this session more long (2 Hours)* : **userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(7200);**

The review :

**web.xml**

`<session-config\>
     <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>`

**loginForm**

`<form method=post action="/j_security_check.jsp" >
    <input type="text"      name= "j_username" >
    <input type="password"  name= "j_password" >
    <input type="checkbox"  name="j_remember"  />
</form>`

**j_security_check.jsp**

```
//Have we already authenticated someone ?
    if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {

        String j_username = request.getParameter("j_username");
        String j_password = request.getParameter("j_password");
        String j_remember = request.getParameter("j_remember");

        try {

            request.login(j_username, j_password);

            if("on".equals(j_remember)){
                session.setAttribute(KEEP_CONNECT, true);
            } else {
                session.setAttribute(KEEP_CONNECT, false);
            }

            logger.debug("Authentication of '" + request.getUserPrincipal() + "' was successful.");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() +HOME_PAGE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex,"Authentication failed.");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + ERROR_PAGE);
        }

    } else {
        logger.debug("Already authenticated '" + request.getUserPrincipal() + "'.");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + LOGIN_PAGE);
    }
```

**SessionManagedBean**

```
private void initTimeOut() {
        String login          =           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
        boolean keepConnected = (boolean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(KEEP_CONNECT);

        logger.debug(login + " IN > " + userSession.getMaxInactiveInterval());
        logger.debug(" keepConnected ? = " + keepConnected);

        if (keepConnected) {
            //keep this session and disable timeOut until the manual deconnexion
            userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
        }

        logger.debug(login + " OUT > " + userSession.getMaxInactiveInterval());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Through the deployment descriptor, setting it to `-1` will make it indefinite:

```
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        -1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: In this case it is **always** indefinite, not what the OP requested